# Inequality in Qlikview set expressions

Tags: qlikview

Example from Qlikview help:

```
sum( {$<Year = {“>1978<2004”}>} Sales )
```

I try this code, but it did't works

```
Count( {$<Damages.DamageDate = {">Min(OtherDate)"}>} Damages.Id)
```

Looks like qlikview did't support dates in inequalities.
Any way if anyowne know how to do things like this please help.

Answer (score 5):

As I remember, you must use a dollar-sign expansion within the set expression. Look up "Set Modifiers with Dollar-Sign Expansions" in the manual. The Min function will then be evaluated and so the set expression should work.

It will look sg like this:

```
Count( {$<Damages.DamageDate = {">$(=Min(OtherDate))"}>} Damages.Id)
```

Or perhaps

```
Count( {$<Damages.DamageDate = {">$(#=Min(OtherDate))"}>} Damages.Id)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use

```
// Reopen or share this result by using the following Url:
// http://tools.qlikblog.at/SetAnalysisWizard/?sa=J0LC

Count({$<[Damages.DamageDate]={">$(=Min(OtherDate))"}>}[Damages.Id])
```

Note: I think you should square brackets for qualified field names like "Damages.DamageDate".
You can use the Set Analysis Wizard to change the expression.

Hope this helps!

Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Another posibility to your question is create a variable for example: `vMinDate = Min(OtherDate)`

And then you can use your variable in the expression like this:

```
Count( {$<Damages.DamageDate = {'$(vMinDate)'}>} Damages.Id)
```

Answer (score -1):

I not find the way how to calculate what I need in qlikview, but I workaround it by make all calculation in sql query.

**UPDATE:**

Also combination of count and if may be helpful. And don't forget place user selected values into document variables before use it in expressions

Comment: You asked for 'Inequality in Qlikview set expressions' then, imho, you should select the other answer (Qlikview-way).

Comment: In this answer I point to solution suitable for me - use combination of count and if expressions (see my update). I supose that qlikview-way to. So I votedup the another answer despite the fact that it is not useful to me. In much cases It will work and it looks like it useful to many. Also I uncheck my answer, so downvoter would be happy.